# Magento 2.4.2 slow with multiple stores

Tags: multi-website, slow-response

Good morning people!
I come to ask for help with magento 2 configured for multiple stores, my problem is that when I have one or two stores it works normally, but our database has more than 20 stores registered and this causes a very long delay for the first load. Once the store is accessed it gets faster!

I've done several tests, increased the capacity of all services and had no improvements, database and services are optimized. We use instances on AWS EC2, AWS RDS database, AWS CLOUDFRONT CDN and AWS ELASTICACHE REDIS.

When you have one or two stores it takes about 1-2 seconds for the first load, but with all our stores it takes about 15 seconds for the first load.

Does anyone have a solution to speed up this initial loading?
We are using Magento 2.4.2 community.

Comment: have you  use Redis?

Comment: You have to disabled some modules which are not required lime MSI module if you are not using  multi source  inventory

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
AWS instance TYPE?, Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.